# Problem with specifying quantity value in FormulaData

Tags: curated-data, units

I wanted to use the formulas for `KineticEnergy` and `KineticEnergyRelativistic` with specific quantity vaules. The later formula does not work as I expected.

First, the `KineticEnergy` formula:

```
FormulaData["KineticEnergy"]
```

[image: KE formula]

Specifying quantity values per the documentation works as expected:

```
FormulaData["KineticEnergy", {"m" -> Quantity[64.8*^-6, "Kilograms"], "v" -> Quantity[0.2, "SpeedOfLight"]}]
```

[image: KE formula with values]

Now, the `KineticEnergyRelativistic` part:

```
keRelFD = FormulaData["KineticEnergyRelativistic"]
```

[image: KE Rel formula]

Again, specifying values:

```
FormulaData["KineticEnergyRelativistic", {"m" -> Quantity[64.8*^-6, "Kilograms"], "v" -> Quantity[0.2, "SpeedOfLight"]}]
```

[image: KE Rel values 1]

When I looked at the result that occurs for a symbolic quantity for the `QuantityVariable`, `v`, I see more details about the problem and possibly why the previous result returned `False`.

```
FormulaData["KineticEnergyRelativistic", {"m" -> Quantity[64.8*^-6, "Kilograms"], "v" -> Quantity[v, "Meters"/"Seconds"]}]
```

[image: KE Rel values 2]

The only way I found to get around this issue it to use apply a rule to the 2nd part of previous result:

```
FormulaData["KineticEnergyRelativistic", {"m" -> Quantity[64.8*^-6, "Kilograms"], "v" -> Quantity[v, "Meters"/"Seconds"]}][[2]] /. v -> QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[0.2, "SpeedOfLight"]]]
```

[image: KE Rel values 3]

While this works, it seems a bit clunky. Does anyone have any idea of how to do this in a way that works like it did for `KineticEnergy`?

I'm running Mathematica 11 on Win 10.

Comment: `FormulaData[
  "KineticEnergyRelativistic", {"m" -> 
    Quantity[64.8*^-6, "Kilograms"], 
   "v" -> Quantity[v, "SpeedOfLight"]}] /. {v -> 0.2}` works too. Btw. I guess you edited-out the second part after && in your final screenshot?

Comment: Probably you discovered a bug, report it.

Comment: @masterxilo, it probably looks like I edited the `&&` out, but I didn't intend to edit it out. If you look closely, I take the 2nd part of the formula result like so `FormulaData[
   "KineticEnergyRelativistic", {"m" -> 
     Quantity[64.8*^-6, "Kilograms"], 
    "v" -> Quantity[v, "Meters"/"Seconds"]}][[2]] /. 
 v -> QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[0.2, "SpeedOfLight"]]]`.

Comment: Ah, it's just missing the part selection in the code you posted.

Comment: @masterxilo, I guess I left that out my original post. Sorry about that. I've edited to fix it. And, I guess I'll report this issue to WRI.